# Adding a version parameter to YII for application version

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

We are building a web application using Yii as the framework. Where would be a good location for us to put a version information array?

This version array is not the version of Yii but the version our application is on. This way we can use it global throughout the application. Example when deploy the application on our servers we can have a conditional that compares the `required_php_version` against the server's php version (`phpversion()`) to throw errors. This is just a simple example.

The array would consist of (with possibility to evolve later):

```
<?php
array(
    'version' => '2.0.1',
    'required_php_version' => '5.4.4'
);
?>
```

Comment: "When installing the application" => how do you "install" it?

Comment: "Installing" might not be the correct word. We basically deploy it on different servers our company owns.

Comment: So it sounds like a job for your deployment tooling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, The best place to put your configurations in an application based on Yii, is `main.php` config file, which is situated in `protected/config/main.php`. But it is important to put your custom configurations in a right place. That is in `params` array. You can put your configs like below in config file:

```
'params' => array(
    'webmaster' => 'YourEmail@example.com',
    'required_php_version' => '5.4.1',
    'my_app_version'=>'2.0.1.1',
    'info_in_array'=>array(1,2,3,4,'so on ...')
    // and so on
 ),
```

You can use these information in everywhere of your application like below:

```
Yii::app()->params['required_php_version'] //which returns 5.4.1 in this example.
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that would be a good place for it but I wanted to see if there was a better spot. This will work perfectly.